# extern "C" function returning std::array

Tags: c++, stdarray, extern-c

The following code compiles with gcc but does not compile with MSVC ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrWVX0AGTy1MAOWcARpjEIACcpAAOqEKE5rR2ji7KUTFmdF4%2B/k5BIeHGmKZxDATMxAQJzq6cRpgmabTFpQQZfoHBYUYlZRVJ1UJdzd6t2e2hAJRGqA7EyBxSAPTzANQAKgCeEZhLa1PES2hYSwjBmKRLJEusqMzoS2pLmOLMThHsAHSaMgCCnz/aAMzeZCOQ6af42UrEZhrMHYX6/R4EYK0JY6bQ2NFLfroEAgSHQsE2KhXZgEUj/WFLGioCBjeEAdn03yWLKWxEwBGmKOxuPxMPBxOuZIp/zhjOq2nJmnpABEwUyfrL4d9lV8pBNWNIAKzyVyyeSoaQYvQGLG7WaogGceQEaRyMYTADWIG03DeoQ9nq9XoAbCppNxdXaDdJ5EIQDJSLb9RM4LAkGgXnh2GQKBBExFk%2B1gEJaMwIkIEKgyVRk0jiOGIAFg6QAt5SmtpNbSImnFYCAB5WisRv60hYJxqYDsGv4dmFABumHDfceBQcSKb8m8SM1fdYeACUOIazsWBrBGIeCcS4mxOYOYAanhMAB3DubPXN/iMFgjnh8OgEYRiSR9pTVKo6goAYBgqJu4aQBMqARPUM5hrUBT1JY1g9FUpDuC0WQ5Mk0SxHQaG4akcRYW0IR9IhhR0I03T2JUyj5FRDQDKRIzkZ0TSEX0LFDNh7ScBMQjmhwAn%2BlIOqkHqcikIaUjiAAHD6AC0PrcEswDIMgSwQIeDi0I6YzabghAXDo/zVEsdhJimlrmYZxr6HoNrBg6pDOq67rel5Hp%2BmugaSTWslhhGUYuaQcaICgqDWcE5CUBmWYhBOyARBEAD6E6cKEaWqEi/RpeIql8GWwSVtWfZ1nmO5Li20VtvQXY9qOmCDuoI59mOSF4FOM7SXOyALnMzYrrUNYbluDZ7nM0mHsep58KoV43vej41S%2BTBsCJvAvj%2BEg1kokpARooF6OBASQbSMmwXE8E1HUcQobYdG9Bh1isTh1QpPh8TPehX31O9/F3V11EDFxwNMTRgyZGRDFg79cNNID5GCcJXAatqQZ9rJhVqU4QjJUsmWhG8uXTgQRn4EQexmRZVmZjZZnaPZJ26M5MZOi6bred5vkBlj0lBUYIXRva4UwJFUwEBEC5xem0UM%2B0kqYFTJDKOtb5bZ%2BggiHtfa3lCETzWuElSSGUgdguMsU6gVBLLjSz44TxOk6S5PafTiW2cz7P2pz2hamJ/lmzJobC5GovqhjUjaAL5u%2B1HpBThWD3cEAA))

```
#include <array>

extern "C" std::array<float,3> foo()
{
    return std::array<float,3>{1,2,3};
}
```

Is one of the compilers is right and the other is wrong, or, is it implementation-defined ?

Comment: Can you run the code compiled with gcc?

Comment: @StureS It's right there `The following code compiles with gcc`

Comment: Yes, compiles! But can you **run** it?

Comment: @StureS Sure - [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/fPs87jj6f) - runs in gcc.

Comment: clang compiles it but issues a warning "may be incompatible with C linkage". What does the standard say for a C function returning a C++ type? [This combination does not seem to be mentioned.](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link) I'd say undefined? Actually according to `10` it may be implementation-defined.

Comment: The memory representation of `std::array<float,3>` is just `float[3]` which is also a valid type in C, so it makes at least some sense that it compiles.